# The game is stopped at 0th scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a gamemanager script for my game and add it at 0th scene.
When the game is start and 0th scene is open, the gamemanager script is activated and have to load 1th scene.

It worked well at first. But when I added the code about google play login, it didn't work and don't load 1th scene. Seems like it just stopped.

```
public class GameMgr : MonoBehaviour {
public static GameMgr instance;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

    instance = this;

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");

    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    Initialize();

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sign in successful!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed to sign in with Google Play");
        }
    });
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}

public void Initialize()
 {
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
}
```

I deleted the code about game data that store at this script

Comment: Which scene is this? `SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");` Use names, not numbers since they have names in your code.  I would guess `Social.localUser.Authenticate` blocks which will stop your whole script until it is finished. Have you run this is the debugger so you can see what is happening?